# JavaScript not working? Randomizer code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code to randomize a background-image in a div element upon page load, however it doesn't seem to be working.

JS in the  section:

```
function Randomize() {
    var images = new Array("<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/flyeuro/images/banners/ban.ner1.jpg","<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/flyeuro/images/banners/banner2.jpg");
    var imageNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    document.getElementById("banner").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + images[imageNum] + "') repeat scroll center center rgb(0, 0, 0)";
}

window.onload = Randomize;
```

HTML:

```
<div id="banner"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div#banner {
    background: url("../images/banners/banner1.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 270px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom: 25px; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 2px 15px 2px ;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px 2px ;
}
```

Comment: "however it doesn't seem to be working." Elaborate on that

Comment: Define "not working."  When you step through the code in a debugger, at what point does the observed behavior deviate from the expected behavior?  What are the relevant runtime values when this happens?

Comment: How can you be confident enough in 'Math.random() * images.length' that you want to use it as-is to index into an array?

Comment: @WilliamMelani what's to not be confident about?

Comment: try this   document.getElementById("banner").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + images[imageNum] + "') repeat scroll center center rgb(0, 0, 0)!important";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting multiple background attributes to the `backgroundImage` property. Instead, just set a `url()`.

If you want to always have those other values, I'd set them in the CSS.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8KsWg/).

Comment: I think that was the issue, it works fine now when I set it in CSS, thank you.